# Target an element when another:checked

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here’s the HTML:

```
<div>
  <label for="n-0">Label</label>
  <input id="n-0" type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

`<!--More content-->`

```
<p class="special"></p>
```

Is there a CSS-only selector that can target `p.special` when `input:checked`? Also notice that `p.special` is a lever higher than `input`.

Comment: Nope there is none, you can't do this in css instead use javascript..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can target an element that is a sibling of `input[type=checkbox]:checked` but not it's parent's sibling.